# How to set compiler to gcc in NDK toolchain with cmake 3.7.2?

Tags: android-ndk, cmake

I use cmake 3.7.2 to compile a c++ source file. I set `CMAKE_ANDROID_STANDALONE_TOOLCHAIN=/my/ndk-toolchain` accronding to official guide, but the default compiler is clang and clang++. I don't know how to set complier to gcc and g++.

Comment: Thanks,but why the default compiler is clang?

Comment: Because gcc is unsupported.

Comment: If you change the name of clang in tool-chain/bin directory, cmake can find and set gcc and g++ compliers as its default compiler.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, clang is the default compiler for NDK applications.
Probably, the toolchain you are using has configured 'clang' as the compiler, but it should be the correct option.

You can check the [readme file of the googlesource site](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk.git/+/master/CHANGELOG.md).

Comment: I find that in source code of cmake, if `clang` and `clang++` exist in toolchain/bin, the cxx compiler will be set as clang. That means clang is default compiler in cmake 3.7.2 for ndk toolchain.